# Macros with lazy var

Tags: ios, swift, macros

I've been exploring Macros and was trying to create one that only returns a lazy var, using the following code:

```swift
public struct SubjectPublisherMacro: PeerMacro {

    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax,
                                 providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntax] {

        return [
            "lazy var state: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = { subject.eraseToAnyPublisher() }()"
        ]
    }
}
```

When applied to a Subject, like the following:

```swift
@SubjectPublisher
private var subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
```

If we expand the macro, the code generated is effectively:

```swift
lazy var state: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = {
    subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

However, when we compile, it gives an error, and we have the following Stack dump:

```
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/xpto/macros/FFMacros/Sources/FFMacrosClient/main.swift -emit-dependencies-path /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.d -emit-const-values-path /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.swiftconstvalues -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.swiftdeps -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.dia -target arm64-apple-macos10.15 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -stack-check -sdk /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk -I /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Products/Debug -I /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/lib -F /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Products/Debug/PackageFrameworks -F /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Products/Debug -F /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -no-color-diagnostics -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -profile-generate -profile-coverage-mapping -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -Onone -D SWIFT_PACKAGE -D DEBUG -D Xcode -serialize-debugging-options -load-plugin-executable /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Products/Debug/FFMacrosMacros#FFMacrosMacros -package-name ffmacros -const-gather-protocols-file /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FFMacrosClient_const_extract_protocols.json -empty-abi-descriptor -validate-clang-modules-once -clang-build-session-file /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/xpto/macros/FFMacros -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -ivfsstatcache -Xcc /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/macosx14.2-23C53-ddea79c7890ab41bba4a63928c655a96.sdkstatcache -Xcc -I/Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Products/Debug/include -Xcc -I/Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DSWIFT_PACKAGE -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -module-name FFMacrosClient -frontend-parseable-output -disable-clang-spi -target-sdk-version 14.2 -target-sdk-name macosx14.2 -external-plugin-path /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/usr/lib/swift/host/plugins#/Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/usr/bin/swift-plugin-server -external-plugin-path /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/usr/local/lib/swift/host/plugins#/Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/usr/bin/swift-plugin-server -external-plugin-path /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/lib/swift/host/plugins#/Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/bin/swift-plugin-server -external-plugin-path /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/local/lib/swift/host/plugins#/Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/bin/swift-plugin-server -plugin-path /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/host/plugins -plugin-path /Applications/Xcode-15.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/local/lib/swift/host/plugins -o /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o -index-unit-output-path /FFMacros.build/Debug/FFMacrosClient.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o -index-store-path /Users/xpto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FFMacros-byrxxptdunfedzeunapzrisyulor/Index.noindex/DataStore -index-system-modules
1.  Apple Swift version 5.9.2 (swiftlang-5.9.2.2.56 clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
2.  Compiling with the current language version
3.  While evaluating request IRGenRequest(IR Generation for file "/Users/macros/FFMacros/Sources/FFMacrosClient/main.swift")
4.  While emitting IR SIL function "@$s14FFMacrosClient4TestC5state7Combine12AnyPublisherVySSs5NeverOGvg".
 for getter for state (at @__swiftmacro_14FFMacrosClient4TestC7subject33_32E41C858868D91DD4497E3BF955E2AFLL16SubjectPublisherfMp_.swift:1:10)
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x000000010728dabc llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 56
1  swift-frontend           0x0000000109ef3cb0 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 112
2  swift-frontend           0x0000000109c5d054 SignalHandler(int) + 352
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000186829a24 _sigtramp + 56
4  swift-frontend           0x00000001098a52a4 swift::irgen::projectPhysicalClassMemberAddress(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Value*, swift::SILType, swift::SILType, swift::VarDecl*, swift::GenericSignature) + 1036
5  swift-frontend           0x00000001098a52a4 swift::irgen::projectPhysicalClassMemberAddress(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Value*, swift::SILType, swift::SILType, swift::VarDecl*, swift::GenericSignature) + 1036
6  swift-frontend           0x0000000106e90ee4 (anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitSILBasicBlock(swift::SILBasicBlock*) + 79544
7  swift-frontend           0x0000000109611fdc swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 11680
8  swift-frontend           0x00000001072109c8 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>,
std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>> const&) + 2516
9  swift-frontend           0x00000001058b59d0 swift::IRGenRequest::evaluate(swift::Evaluator&, swift::IRGenDescriptor) const + 6532
10 swift-frontend           0x0000000105188adc swift::SimpleRequest<swift::IRGenRequest, swift::GeneratedModule (swift::IRGenDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)9>::evaluateRequest(swift::IRGenRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 176
11 swift-frontend           0x0000000106b59f64 llvm::Expected<swift::IRGenRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::IRGenRequest>(swift::IRGenRequest const&) + 1480
12 swift-frontend           0x0000000108e00fb8 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::FileUnit*, swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::TBDGenOptions const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule>>, llvm::StringRef, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::StringRef, llvm::GlobalVariable**) + 264
13 swift-frontend           0x00000001097cd99c generateIR(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::TBDGenOptions const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule>>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::StringRef, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, llvm::GlobalVariable*&, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>) + 156
14 swift-frontend           0x00000001097d56d4 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule>>, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1596
15 swift-frontend           0x00000001097d0a08 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1748
16 swift-frontend           0x00000001097d4854 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 4568
17 swift-frontend           0x000000010983bd44 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 4408
18 dyld                     0x00000001864790e0 start + 2360
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file "default.profraw": Operation not permitted
```

If we modify our macro to return a computed var instead of a lazy var, we can compile successfully. However, our goal was to return the lazy var. Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is probably a compiler bug. You should submit a bug report.