# Is that possible to override the varible using macro?

Tags: swift, swift-macro

I want to create a macro to protect the initialization process of lazy varibles. For example:

```swift
@ThreadSafeLazy(lock: lock)
lazy var varible: Int = {
    return 1 + 1
}()

// will expanded to 

lazy var varible: Int = {
    lock.around {
        if let _unique_name_varible { return _unique_name_varible }
        _unique_name_varible = { 
            return 1 + 1 
        }()
        return _unique_name_varible 
    }
}()

var _unique_name_varible: Int? = nil
```

I know how to add a `_unique_name_varible` varible using `PeerMacro` here, but I have no idea how to override the `varible`'s initiate closure.

---

- #1 Edit:

Due to the `lazy var` generation compiler crash issue, I changed the solution for workaround. now the macro looks like:

```swift
@Lazify(name: "internalClassName", lock: "SomeClass.classLock")
func createLazyVariable() -> String {
  return "__" + NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
}

// expanded to
private(set) var _lazy_internalClassName: String? = nil

var internalClassName: String {
    if let exsist = self._lazy_internalClassName {
        return exsist
    }
    return SomeClass.classLock.around { [weak self] in
        guard let self else {
            fatalError()
        }
        if let exsist = self._lazy_internalClassName {
            return exsist
        }
        let temp = self.createLazyVariable()
        self._lazy_internalClassName = temp
        return temp
    }
}
```

But there's another problem I encountered, I raised another topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78236261/why-circular-reference-expanding-peer-macros-here)

Comment: `lazy` is a really old language feature, that predates macros and property wrappers. It probably wouldn't even be added to the language today, if it didn't already exist. You're better off just making your own `@Lazy` property wrapper, no macro required

Comment: @Alexander Hi thanks for your information, and I tried using property wrapper to archive this but the biggest problem is that it can't use `self` in both property wrapper's declaration and varible's initialization closure. So I gave up to use it and try macro here.

Comment: You can use [`_enclosingInstance`](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/accessing-a-swift-property-wrappers-enclosing-instance/) to access `self` from the property wrapper, though that only works for classes. Referencing `self` from the closure though... yeah that'd be an issue :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify existing declarations using a macro, except for adding accessors to a property.

As a workaround, you can make the lazy var declarations *a parameter of a freestanding declaration macro*. That is,

```
#ThreadSafeLazy(lock: lock) {
    lazy var variable: Int = {
        return 1 + 1
    }()
}
```

You would add an additional `() -> Void` closure argument to `ThreadSafeLazy`, so that users of the macro can declare lazy vars in the closure. The macro can then expand to the two declarations you want.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
enum ThreadSafeLazy: DeclarationMacro {
    
    static func generatePair(_ varDecl: VariableDeclSyntax, uniqueName: TokenSyntax, lock: ExprSyntax) -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard let binding = varDecl.bindings.first,
              let initialiser = binding.initializer?.value,
              let type = binding.typeAnnotation?.type,
              let name = binding.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?.identifier else {
            return []
        }
        let initialiserWithLock: DeclSyntax = """
        lazy var \(name): \(type) = {
            \(lock).around { () -> \(type) in
                if let \(uniqueName) { return \(uniqueName) }
                let temp: \(type) = \(initialiser)
                \(uniqueName) = temp
                return temp
            }
        }()
        """
        let backingProperty: DeclSyntax = """
        var \(uniqueName): Optional<\(type)> = nil
        """
        return [initialiserWithLock, backingProperty]
    }
    
    static func expansion(
        of node: some FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax]
    {
        let varDecls = node.trailingClosure!.statements.compactMap { $0.item.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self) }
        let lockExpr = node.argumentList.first!.expression
        return varDecls.flatMap {
            generatePair($0, uniqueName: context.makeUniqueName("backingProperty"), lock: lockExpr)
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, you don't even need to write `lazy` explicitly in the variable declaration, because that can also be added by `ThreadSafeLazy`. Though IMO that could create confusion.

It is possible to declare *multiple* lazy vars in the closure, so you can also consider a design like what I did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78124359/5133585):

```
#ThreadSafeLazy {
    @Locked(lock1)
    lazy var variable`: Int = {
        return 1 + 1
    }()

    @Locked(lock2)
    lazy var variable2: Int = {
        return 2 + 2
    }()
}
```

where `ThreadSafeLazy` expands to all the declaration inside the closure, but if any of the declarations has a `@Locked` macro attached, `ThreadSafeLazy` generates the thread safe version of the property, along with the additional unique name property. `Locked` doesn't need to expand to anything - it only acts as a marker for `ThreadSafeLazy`.

Comment: Thank you , I will try to understand the information and have a try

Comment: @KleinMioke I added a simple implementation. However, I just remembered that there is a compiler bug that causes the compiler to crash when generating `lazy var`s, see [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/macros-with-lazy-var/69747) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77928385/5133585). You can still see that the macro expands correctly using "Expand Macro" in Xcode though. Hopefully they fix this at some point.

Comment: thanks, I tried temporarily avoiding this crash by using a computed property, and it works well. However, the solution is now a bit non-intuitive. And I met another issue when working on it. Can you please take a look at the latest edit?.