# Why "Circular reference expanding peer macros" here

Tags: swift, swift-macro

I'm making a macro like this:

```swift
@attached(peer, names: arbitrary)
public macro Lazify(name: String, lock: Protectable) = #externalMacro(module: "MacroModule", type: "LazifyMacro")
```

It should be used to attach to a function declaration, to generate some other variables.

But I got the error `Circular reference expanding peer macros on <function_name>`, the code is below:

```swift
class SomeClass {
  
  var _internal_lock: NSLock = .init()
  static let classLock: NSLock = .init()
  
  // Error: Circular reference expanding peer macros on 'createLazyVariable()'
  @Lazify(name: "internalClassName", lock: SomeClass.classLock) 
  func createLazyVariable() -> String {
    return "__" + NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
  }
}
```

If I change the `lock: Protectable` to `lock: String` then it's ok, but it won't have type check when using the macro.

And further if I use a instance property lock `_internal_lock` and the error will change to `Instance member '_internal_lock' cannot be used on type 'SomeClass'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

So I wonder why I can't use the `classLock` or the `_internal_lcok` here?

---

- Edit1

If I use a global instance lock then it can compile:

```swift
let globalLock: NSLock = .init()

class SomeClass {
  @Lazify(name: "internalClassName", lock: globalLock)
  func createLazyVariable() -> String {
    return "__" + NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a circular reference because to resolve the name `SomeClass.classLock`, Swift must first expand `Lazify`. Why? Because `Lazify` can introduce `arbitrary` names, so the meaning of `SomeClass.classLock` might be different after `@Lazify` is expanded. `@Lazify` can't affect names outside of its scope, so if you use a name that is declared in a different class, or global `let`, it works. I'm not sure about this explanation though - it might as well be a bug, perhaps related to [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/66450).

In any case, it seems like `Lazify` would add a declaration with the name of whatever string is passed to its `name` parameter. This is not a good design, since, at least, it would be difficult to rename this using the "Refactor -> Rename" option in Xcode.

Instead of generating whatever name the user wants, you can use the `suffixed` or `prefixed` options in `@attached(peer, names: ...)`, and always generate a name from the name of the declaration to which the macro is attached. For example, use:

```
@attached(peer, names: suffixed(_lazify)) 
// you can write multiple "suffixed(...)" here, if you need
```

Then,

```
@Lazify(lock: SomeClass.classLock)
func createLazyVariable() -> String { ... }
```

should be implemented to generate `createLazyVariable_lazify`.

---

You can't use instance properties here for a similar reason to why something like this doesn't work:

```
class Foo {
    let x = 1
    let y = x // "self" is not available here!
}
```

I think this is checked before the macro expansion, so this is not a problem of your macro, per se.

To allow instance members, you can add an overload like this:

```
public macro Lazify<T, P: Protectable>(lock: KeyPath<T, P>) = ...
```

Usage:

```
@Lazify(lock: \SomeClass._internal_lock)

// in the macro implementation, you would generate something like this:
self[keyPath: \SomeClass._internal_lock]
// to access the lock.
```

---

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78204619/5133585), it seems like a better design would be to just use a property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Lazify<T> {
    let lock: Protectable
    let initialiser: () -> T
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        mutating get { 
            if let x = lazy {
                return x
            }
            return lock.around {
                if let x = self.lazy {
                    return x
                }
                let temp = initialiser()
                self.lazy = temp
                return temp
            }
        }

        set { lazy = newValue }
    }
    
    private(set) var lazy: T?
}
```

If you *really* want a macro, you can make `Lazify` an `accessor` macro as well. Declare the `internalClassName` property yourself and pass the code in `createLazyVariable` to the macro as a closure.

```
@attached(peer, names: prefixed(_lazy_))
@attached(accessor, names: named(get), named(set))
public macro Lazify<T>(lock: Protectable, initialiser: () -> T) = ...
```

```
@Lazify(lock: SomeClass.classLock) {
    return "__" + NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
}
var internalClassName: String

// expands to
private(set) var _lazy_internalClassName: String? = nil
var internalClassName: String {
    get {
        if let exsist = self._lazy_internalClassName {
            return exsist
        }
        return SomeClass.classLock.around { [weak self] in
            guard let self else {
                fatalError()
            }
            if let exsist = self._lazy_internalClassName {
                return exsist
            }
            let temp = "__" + NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
            self._lazy_internalClassName = temp
            return temp
        }
    }

    set { _lazy_internalClassName = newValue }
}
```

Comment: The property wrapper's biggest problem is it can't use `self` in its initialiser, like: `@Lazify(initialiser: self.foo) var value: Int` is not allowed. I don't know if there is any approach to avoid this.

And the `accessor` should be totally great idea. I will update my code to have a try.